# Visual Studio 2019: Cannot open file 'libboost_serialization-vc141-mt-x64-1_66.lib'

Tags: c++, boost

As the title says, I have already done everything, like adding the *boost root* directory in **C/C++ - Additional Include Directories** and adding *boost root/stage/libs* in **Linker - Additional Library Directories**.

I'm currently using VS 2019 Community Edition 16.11.5.

Any help will be appreciated!

[Here is my *boost* directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSlkM.png)

Comment: Did you _build_ boost?

Comment: Your version is vc141. But you compiler ist vc142. If you use auto linking this is difficult to get it working. Either build boost yourself or use the appropiate libraries for your compiler.

Comment: You should first verify that this exact file name exists. I have boost-1.67 which I built from source in 2019 and it names the libs with 141 and this works for VS 2019. However I have not built a more recent version since this is for work purposes where we don't update the third dependencies frequently.

Comment: [Build Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/tools/build/doc/html/index.html). And it is as simple as `.\bootstrap.bat` then `.\b2`. b2 will target `/stage/lib` by default.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I have done it but I have run bootstrap.bat and then b2. There is now stage/lib folder in my boost directory

Comment: @drescherjm Yeah, I can't find the exactly file, "libboost_serialization-vc-mt-**gd**-x64-1_66.lib" is the one that I can find

Comment: Maybe you did not build the release libraries.

Comment: @drescherjm How to do so, can you tell me?

Comment: I build with `--without-python --without-mpi  address-model=64 --toolset=msvc-14.1 --build-type=complete stage install` along with setting the path of the source and destination as I build boost out of source.